# Why is my PHP botched through one host, but rendered perfectly fine through another?

Tags: php, html, doctype, frameset

I created a quirky little random-color generator in a class last year while learning php as a beginner on the server the teacher had set up for students:

http://tony.rop.launchbrigade.com/random_squares.php

Recently, I bought a domain with Namecheap and put a small LAMP server on a Raspberry pi. I literally copied and pasted the `random_squares.php` into VIM at

http://modjo.xyz/Colorful_Squares.php

I did notice that the php seemed to be processed a lot more on the modjo.xyz server, after inspecting the source.

So, my main question is, what do Framesets do, and why does it so drastically alter the PHP? In the source, the lower part of the function that generates the squares was pasted above the first part of the function. I haven't touched php in a while, but I'm assuming this has to do with either Namecheap, or the DOCTYPE declaration, or both. Is there a way to not have my code altered by Namecheap?

Here's the full page for clarity (No CSS or anything, all self-contained):

```
<HTML>

    <STYLE>
    TD {
        padding: 0px;
        border: 5px solid inherit;
        margin: 10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        }

    </STYLE>
    <TITLE>Randomly Colored Squares</TITLE>
    <BODY>
        <DIV align="left" bgcolor="#FF00FF">

        <TABLE bgcolor="DDDDDD" border="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%" height="10%">
            <TR>
                <TD colspan="2">
                     <CENTER><head><font face="helvetica" size="20" color="EEE"><b>Tony's Interweb Page</b></font></head></CENTER>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>


        </DIV>
        <CENTER><H2><font face="helvetica" size="12" color="EEE"><b>Randomly Colored Rectangles!</b></font></H2></CENTER>
        <TABLE border="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%">

        <?php
        $rowcount = 9;
        $colcount = 5;
        $fitwidth = "150px";//(100/$colcount);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $rowcount; $i++)
        {
            echo '<TR height="200px" margin="10px">';
            for ($x = 0; $x < $colcount; $x++)
            {
                $color = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 6);


                echo '<TD width="'.$fitwidth.'%" bgcolor="'.$color.'" margin="10px"><font face="helvetica" size="12" color="FFFFFF"><b>'.$color.'</b></font></TD>'."\n";
            }
            echo '</TR>';
        }
        ?>

        </TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: An obvious error I spot is `$fitwidth = "150px";` and `<TD width="'.$fitwidth.'%"` wich will result in `width="150px%"` which is probably not what you want

Comment: I don't think the frameset is the issue. The problem you seem to have, seems to be that the php is not handled correctly as can be seen by the partial code output. Can you post the Apache+PHP Version you are using? Did you install PHP+Apache through a package repo or from a download?

Comment: PHP doesn't work on `76.21.107.189` look at source of `Colorful_Squares.php`. If you ever see PHP code client side you have an issue (unless making a tutorial site, or documenting it).

Comment: Are you sure it was last year and not a decade ago? Lol.

Comment: @dbrumann Apache Version: 2.4.10. After a little more googling, I think I may not have installed php5 correctly, so I'll see if an update/reboot will change anything

Comment: Okay, this is resolved. Previously, I had been following [this tutorial](http://raspipress.com/2012/09/tutorial-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-raspberry-pi/) and thought php was part of the php-mysql install. Lesson learned. http://modjo.xyz/Colorful_Squares.php works just as intended now.